# Total file system freezes after server disconnection with sshfs

Tags: ssh, filesystems, vpn, sshfs

I access a server through vpn (with forticlient sslvpn) and mount a file system on my laptop with sshfs. But sometimes i get randomly disconnected from the vpn. When this happens not only I lose access to the mounted directory but my home directory gets frozen as well. Generally it lasts about 20 minutes until it automatically goes back to normal.
Does someone know how to prevent this from happening? (I am a beginner on linux so forgive me any misunderstanding)

Comment: Hello, Welcome to Unix & Linux. I'm not wanting to assume - are both the local server and remote server linux? Or other operating systems? 
Is the mount point somewhere used by system processes? That sounds like an important bit of information.
Which distro are you using? Perhaps some log output would help.

Comment: Thanks! I use Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS locally. The remote server is Ubuntu 18.04.5. Yes, I am running some jupyter notebooks that read files on the mount point.

Comment: There may be some output in /var/log/kern.log or /var/log/dmesg if more than the mountpoint freezes. Can you check it for any related output and post that please? Am I right to presume this is using Fuse?